# Jupyterlab container cannot connect to kafka localhost server on port 9092

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-kafka, docker-compose, jupyter

I have docker-compose containing a kafka server, a zookeeper, spark and a jupyter-lab.
This is my code of jupyter-lab dockerfile

```
ARG debian_buster_image_tag=8-jre-slim
FROM openjdk:${debian_buster_image_tag}
RUN mkdir -p ${shared_workspace} && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3 && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    pip3 install pyspark==3.0.1 jupyterlab==2.1.5
```

This is my code of docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.6"
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "hadoop-distributed-file-system"
    driver: local
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyterlab
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace

  spark-master:
    image: spark-master
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-worker-1:
    image: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
  spark-worker-2:
    image: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8082:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    expose:
    - "2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    expose:
    - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
```

In jupyter lab I cannot access to kafka:9093, localhost:9092 by sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9093") ..., it showed that error:

```
20/12/03 16:10:23 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-4b4422bc-2a6a-456a-b750-4fba8300328c-37706672-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-4b4422bc-2a6a-456a-b750-4fba8300328c-37706672-driver-0] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I also installed telnet to check connection via bash of jupyterlab, I can telnet to some servers like `telnet www.cyberciti.biz 80`, but cannot connect to localhost:9092. Please help me.

Comment: Your error says it's connected to localhost:9092, not kafka:9093... So which did you actually use?

Answer (score 0):

Per @onecricketeer, I think my previous answer is a red-herring.

So, I ran your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml` and, it works for me.

```
ARG debian_buster_image_tag=8-jre-slim
FROM openjdk:${debian_buster_image_tag}

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip3 install pyspark==3.0.1 jupyterlab==2.1.5

ENTRYPOINT [ "jupyter","notebook","--allow-root","--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

**NOTE**

- Removed `${shared_workspace}` as this appears mounted to `/opt/workspace`
- Reordered the `apt-get install`s
- Added `ENTRYPOINT`
- Run `jupyter-notebook --allow-root -ip=0.0.0.0`

This exposes the notebook service on `localhost:8888` but requires a token.

Tweaked the Compose:

```
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyterlab
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
```

Then:

```sh
docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

And `docker-compose ps`:

```
        Name                      Command               State                            Ports                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
65130144_kafka_1       start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, 9093/tcp                        
65130144_zookeeper_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up      2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp                    
jupyterlab             jupyter notebook --allow-r ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp                                  
spark-master           /bin/bash /master.sh             Up      6066/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
spark-worker-1         /bin/bash /worker.sh             Up      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                                  
spark-worker-2         /bin/bash /worker.sh             Up      0.0.0.0:8082->8081/tcp
```

You'll likely want the Notebook's token, use `docker-compose logs jupyterlab`:

```
Attaching to jupyterlab
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.412 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.659 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jupyterlab
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.659 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.662 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.662 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.5 is running at:
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.662 NotebookApp] http://1b77e2b01d7b:8888/?token=e1796ee09331bd31459211ce35ad16fc9a7f4ee854870457
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.662 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e1796ee09331bd31459211ce35ad16fc9a7f4ee854870457
jupyterlab        | [I 17:57:08.662 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
jupyterlab        | [W 17:57:08.665 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
jupyterlab        | [C 17:57:08.666 NotebookApp] 
jupyterlab        |     
jupyterlab        |     To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
jupyterlab        |         file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html
jupyterlab        |     Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
jupyterlab        |         http://1b77e2b01d7b:8888/?token=e1796ee09331bd31459211ce35ad16fc9a7f4ee854870457
jupyterlab        |      or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e1796ee09331bd31459211ce35ad16fc9a7f4ee854870457
```

Used the 2nd link (you'll need to use whatever token is generated), created a notebook and added:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession;


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9093")
```

And ran it:

```
<pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader at 0x7fbf8defe208>
```

Which seems (!?) Ok.

[image]

<strike>I suspect `jupyter-lab` and `jupyterlab` are the same in your config.</strike>

The Dockerfile does not run (no `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`) anything when it's started so I'm also assuming you're using a shell in it. This is fine just unusual.

Couple of things with the `kafka` service (**NOTE** I'm only cursorily familiar with Kafka):

- within the `kafka` service you must reference it as `localhost`
- You have `INSIDE://kafka:9093` but that has 2 problems. Inside the service, it should reference itself as `localhost` and inside the service I suspect it's on port `:8082`
- the statement `expose: - "9093"` is not functional but documentary and it's incorrect unless your image is silently also exposing `:9093`; this does not actual expose anything and so it may be incorrect.

Comment: This isn't the issue. `INSIDE://kafka:9093` gets stored in Zookeeper, and is given to external clients (like pyspark). It's fine